# query on custom field via webservice

Tags: java, soap, rally

I customized the content of Defect in my Rally workspace adding a new custom field.

This custom field is of type string, its name is CustomTest and its display name is CustomAttribute.

I added the value "test" on a defect, but I can't create a working query on that custom field (I'm developing in Java and using the ws api for rally).

the query I tried are

String query8 = "(CustomAttribute = \"test\")";
String query9 = "(CustomAttribute = \"test\")";

Comment: Are you using Rally's new alpha Java REST API?

http://developer.rallydev.com/help/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api or are you writing against the REST endpoints. Are you receiving any errors of note?

A handy place to test your query syntax interactively before running in code is the Rally webservices API documentation:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

Each artifact has a handy "Query" dialog that lets you run example query syntax to see what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rally queries, you must reference the actual field name rather than the Display Name. Thus, if you do:

```
    String query8 = "(CustomTest = \"test\")"; String query9 = "(CustomTest = \"test\")";
```

Then I'd expect your query to work. The info in my comment re: using WSAPI docs to assist running/testing queries outside code should still be useful to you.

Comment: It still doesnt work, but maybe the problem is not on the query, because also other simple queries on defects dont work anymore.

The message I get is

"faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.rallydev.webservice.v1_34.domain.Defect - CustomAttribute"

Comment: Ok, thank you. The problem was that the Java code was generated before the custom attribute was added (I didnt know) and I always got the error 

faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.rallydev.webservice.v1_34.domain.Defect - CustomAttribute

so the problem was not, indeed, on the query code.

Comment: Ah yes, it wasn't clear that you were using SOAP. When you are using the Java SOAP interface, you have to refresh your WSDL and re-generate the Java stub classes when new fields are created in your Rally workspace, so that the Java classes match the data being serialized in Rally's SOAP responses.